# Asus X200MA Notebook RAM upgrade

Tags: memory

I want to upgrade current 2GB RAM of my X200MA to 4 GB. However, to retain 2-year warranty (I have just bought it within last 3 months), I have to do it through warranty department. I called them and they said I had to obtain the RAM and they would install it.

My problem is whether to buy a 2GB RAM stick or a 4GB because I don't know how many RAM slots it has. popular programs such as hwinfo32 and Speccy did not show the number of RAM slots, but Windows 8.1's Taskmanager says "1 of 2 slots used" for RAM. By the way the system is so densely packed, thus without a simple back cover for RAM unlike many laptops, so I cannot open the case myself.

Is there a reliable program to show number of RAM slots? I ask because in case of it having only one slot, I have to buy a 4GB stick to replace the current 2GB. Otherwise (two slots), I can add another 2GB, which is much cheaper than a 4GB, alongside the existent 2GB one.

RAM analysis reports are as follows in Speccy,Hwinfo32, and Windows 8.1 Task Manager, respectively:

```
Speccy:
RAM
        Memory
            Type    DDR3
            Size    1936 MBytes
            DRAM Frequency  666.4 MHz
            CAS# Latency (CL)   9 clocks
            RAS# to CAS# Delay (tRCD)   7 clocks
            RAS# Precharge (tRP)    7 clocks
            Cycle Time (tRAS)   15 clocks
        Physical Memory
            Memory Usage    75 %
            Total Physical  1.89 GB
            Available Physical  475 MB
            Total Virtual   3.83 GB
            Available Virtual   1.51 GB
        SPD
            Number Of SPD Modules   0
------------------------------------------------
Hwinfo32:
General information                                                             
Total Memory Size:                                                              1935 MBytes

Current Performance Settings                                                    
Current Memory Clock:                                                           666.7 MHz
Current Timing (tCAS-tRCD-tRP-tRAS):                                            9.0-9-9-24

Command Rate:                                                                   1T
Read to Read Delay (tRD_RD) Different Rank:                                     6T
Read to Read Delay (tRD_RD) Different DIMM:                                     6T
Write to Write Delay (tWR_WR) Different Rank:                                   6T
Write to Write Delay (tWR_WR) Different DIMM:                                   6T
Read to Write Delay (tRD_WR) Same Rank:                                         9T
Read to Write Delay (tRD_WR) Different Rank:                                    7T
Read to Write Delay (tRD_WR) Different DIMM:                                    6T
Write to Read Delay (tWR_RD) Same Rank (tWTR):                                  16T
Write to Read Delay (tWR_RD) Different Rank:                                    5T
Write to Read Delay (tWR_RD) Different DIMM:                                    6T
Read to Precharge Delay (tRTP):                                                 6T
Write to Precharge Delay (tWTP):                                                21T
Write Recovery Time (tWR):                                                      10T
RAS# to RAS# Delay (tRRD):                                                      5T
Four Activate Window (tFAW):                                                    30T
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Win 8.1 Task Manager (screen shot):

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you ask the warranty department?

Comment: I did! they didn't know it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAM is onboard. I had it opened by a technician to see if it supported RAM extension. Unfortunately, there were no slots. The RAM is onboard for this notebook. That is to say, it is part of the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

A search quickly found this: http://www.91mobiles.com/asus-x200ma-kx141d-celeron-quad-core-3rd-gen-2-gb-500-gb-dos-laptop-price-in-india-65706

It says there is one slot.

Comment: mine is X200MA-KX060D. I'm not sure they have the same memory configurations.

Comment: 1 slot: http://www.snapdeal.com/product/asus-x200makx141d-laptop-4th-gen/1807227541

Comment: it is not still the same model.

Comment: Search for yourself, but there is no doubt in my mind that there is only one slot. It is a very inexpensive device and they will cut down on anything "unnecessary".

Comment: Thanks anyhow. Then, why does win 8.1 show "1 of 2 slots used"? As CPU is fairly strong (Pentium Quad 2.16 GHz), it is also probable that they designed two slots.

Comment: My modification of X200MA model has 2-cores Pentium with hyperthreading. I nof found modifications of X200MA with Pentium Quad @jasonstack

Comment: @AlexanderI.Grafov there are different versions most probably. My exact model number is X200MA-KX060D which has four physical cores. [This](http://esam.ir/itemView.aspx/1097682/%D9%84%D9%BE-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%BE-ASUS-X200MA.htm) is exactly it.

Comment: Thank for your note @JasonStack, I searched again and found [specs](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X200MA/specifications/) for this model where Quad Core mentioned as option.

Comment: No problem @AlexanderI.Grafov. This machine has a powerful CPU but its 2 GB RAM is frustratingly low and insufficient for multi-programming.